# Enable gzip with docker and bitnami/nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, gzip, bitnami

I deployed a website with docker and `bitnami/nginx` as image: https://www.10studio.tech/demo. After deployment, I realized that files like `analyzejs.js` was not gzipped:

[image]

Here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  docusaurus:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.16
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./build:/app
    - ./certs:/certs:ro
    - ./my_server_block.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf:ro
    ports:
    - "3001:3001"
    - "3002:3002"
```

Here is `my_server_block.conf`:

```
server {
  listen  3002;
  absolute_redirect off;
  root  /app;

  location = / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen  3001 ssl;

  ssl_certificate      /certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /certs/server.key;

  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
  }
}
```

Here is `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`, where gzip seems to be enabled:

```
I have no name!@8317023de7ec:/app$ cat /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
# Based on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#nginx-conf
# user              www www;  ## Default: nobody

worker_processes  auto;
error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log";
pid               "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/nginx.pid";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format    main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                       '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log    "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/access.log";
    add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    client_body_temp_path  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/client_body" 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/proxy" 1 2;
    fastcgi_temp_path      "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/fastcgi" 1 2;
    scgi_temp_path         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/scgi" 1 2;
    uwsgi_temp_path        "/opt/bitnami/nginx/tmp/uwsgi" 1 2;

    sendfile           on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    tcp_nodelay        off;
    gzip               on;
    gzip_http_version  1.0;
    gzip_comp_level    2;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_types         text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    ssl_protocols      TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/*.conf";

    # HTTP Server
    server {
        # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT
        listen  8080;

        location /status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here and how I could enable gzip?

Comment: I can see that you have managed to gzip your files. Could you please share what was the solution? I am facing with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also just stumbled over the same problem. It seems like the docker image already has gzip enabled. I also have an nginx deployed for the whole server which acts as reverse proxy for the different docker container in the server. What worked for me is to also enabled gzip in the global nginx configuration /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

Don't know if you also have a wrapping nginx. Hope this helps.